# Deleting a channel on slack.com

Tags: slack

I created two channels on my Slack team with a typo. I want to delete them but it seems there is no way?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try searching the help documentation?

From: [Leaving, archiving, or deleting a channel](https://slack.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201375146-Leaving-archiving-or-deleting-a-channel)

> ### Deleting a channel
>
> Because channel deletion is a destructive activity, only Team Owners
>   and Admins can delete channels. *If a channel is deleted, all of its
>   content will be removed from your team's Slack archives permanently.
>   We are unable to restore deleted channels.*
>
> To delete a channel:
>
> 1. Go to your team's channel list at https://my.slack.com/archives
> 2. On the **Channels** tab, click the channel name.
> 3. Click the red **Delete channel** link.
> 4. Check **Yes, I am absolutely sure** and click **Delete it**.
>
> **Note:** The #general channel cannot be deleted.

Comment: If you archive channel it disappears from the channels list.
Red "delete channel" link available only if channel is empty (after deleting all messages).

Comment: @jaepage thanks yes the content of the app has changed.

Comment: @gkislin I emptied my channel and no red delete channel link.  i deleted all messages in the channel and I'm still not offered a delete channel option.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the channel you want to delete. At the top right corner click on options > Additional options > Delete this channel.

[image: Top right corner]

You can also archive the channel if you don't want to loose all the information on it forever.

Answer (score 1):

Only **team owners** and **admins** have permissions to delete a channel.

The current up-to-date help article on deleting channels is here: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/213185307

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the whole **#general** channel that can't be done via https://my.slack.com/archives. You could use this Firefix + Selenium IDE solution at https://github.com/imZack/slack-delete-all-messages.

Answer (score 0):

I was already an admin on Slack and could not see the full menu in order to delete. I was then made primary owner but it made no difference.  What no-one has mentioned is that **to delete a group you have to be a member of that group!**  Only once I became a member could I see 'additional options' to be able to delete.

Answer (score 0):

If the #general channel has been renamed, rename it back to #general, it cannot be deleted