# Delete or make a private Slack channel public

Tags: slack

I declared by mistake a channel as private on Slack (actually because I didn't realize at first that public meant public to the team only).

Now I can't seem to be able to delete it, although I removed all messages. It can't be be switched to public either.

It looks like once you create a private channel, it will always exist and be private.

What's the rationale behind this? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Any help in the answers to [Deleting a channel on slack.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/85908/354)?

Comment: I checked this link but it does not address the specific problem of private channels.

Answer (score 9):

I contacted Slack and got an answer, it looks like this is an expected behavior, here is part of that answer:

> As you pointed out, it's unfortunately not possible to change a private channel to a public one at this time, as information often shared in those channels is of a private nature which is why we do not offer this option.

The answer also provides a workaround which consists in renaming and archiving the private channel, and creating a new public channel with the initial name.