# How do you export a private channel on Slack (e.g. a personal private channel)?

Tags: slack

I am trying to export (download all msgs, data etc... | backup) a 2 private channels: one of my personal private chat with myself.. and one with another member (DM).

I have only found tutorials for archiving a public channel not a private one, but have seen answers that would suggest that arching a private channel is possible: [Deleting/Make private channel public?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102488/delete-or-make-a-private-slack-channel-public)

Comment: To clarify are you trying to archive a channel (make it read only) or export a channel (download all msgs)?

Comment: @JohnC export / thanks i updated question