# Cannot find "delete channel" option in Slack

Tags: slack

I clicked on additional options as mentioned at
[Deleting a channel on slack.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/85908/deleting-a-channel-on-slack-com)
but all I can see is "archive" button, no "delete" (I just created the channel, there is no message yet).

Comment: One thing to consider is that the #default channel cannot be deleted, even if you had renamed it. Sometimes this gets in the way, tripped me up quite a bit until I figured it out!

Answer (score 3):

To delete a channel:

1. Open the channel
2. Click on the cog icon to open "Channel Settings".
3. Click on additional options
4. Click on "Delete this channel"

If you don't see that option you might lack the rights to delete it. Also not that this only works for public channels. Private channels can not be deleted from the Slack client.